# Spring Batch: Delegate to Processor based on Data

Tags: spring-batch

I am fairly new to spring batch and I would appreciate some direction...

I am using chunk processor. I would like to create a job that depending on the filename, a specific processor will chosen.

For example:
For file: testfile-1.txt use processor: TestFileProcessor1.java
For file: testfile-2.txt use processor: TestFileProcessor2.java

I prefer only having ONE chunk processor and have a prior task hook in the correct processor

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JobExecutionDecider` to flow your code to correct step.
You have an abstract step (`BaseStep`) when reader and writer are defined, but not processor and defined 3 concrete step where you bound the correct processor

```
<batch:step id="StepTestFile1" parent="BaseStep">
  <batch:processor ref="path.to.TestFileProcessor1" />
</batch:step>
```

and so on.
In you `JobExecutionDecider` you can go to correct step based on filename (pseudo-code):

```
class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
  public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution,StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if(filename is testfile-1.txt) return new FlowExecutionStatus("StepTestFile1");
    if(filename is testfile-2.txt) return new FlowExecutionStatus("StepTestFile2");
    if(filename is testfile-3.txt) return new FlowExecutionStatus("StepTestFile3");
  }
}
```